# How to set name of an Emacs frame?

Tags: frames

I am new to Emacs, I use text Emacs (inside Putty) and I am from Vim land. So, bare with me about the terminologies that I use.

I want to have a custom string in the mode line for the frame name (to remember why I created this frame) as the defaults like "F6" is of no use to me.

[image: Frame F6 with the output of (frame-list) function]

I found [how to create new frame](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Frames.html#Creating-Frames) and [set-frame-parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Parameter-Access.html#Parameter-Access)  from gnu.org. I gave a try to create new frame from elisp (the first link):

```
(setq x '(("name" . "parsing")))
(make-frame x)
```

But the frame it created has the name F6. I checked it executing `(frame-list)` (shown in picture above).
What am I doing wrong here? Is there an easy way?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter name needs to be a [*symbol*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbols.html) rather than a *string*, i.e.

```
(make-frame '((name . "parsing")))
```

rather than

```
(make-frame '(("name" . "parsing")))
```